# set options of dropdown select to be the selected ones of another multiselect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How can I use jQuery or javascript to set the options of a dropdown select to be the ones that are selected in another multiselect on the same page?

I'm using Php CodeIgniter for my project.
This a part of the code

```
<div>
         <h4>Languages</h4>
         <?php if(isset($languages)) : echo form_multiselect('avail_lang[]', $languages, 'en', 'id="lang_select"'); endif;?>
   </div>
   <label for="def_lang">Default language:</label>
   <?php if(isset($languages)) : echo form_dropdown('def_lang', $languages, 'en'); endif;?>
```

Comment: add some codes, **what have to tried** so far?

Comment: nothing much really, I've just started working with JQuery and php :s